# Select 1 field and group by it (my query isnt working)

Tags: c#, linq

My query below, what im trying to do is get all the records with that quoteID and then group by that ID

```
  var CurSuppliers = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Where(i => i.QuoteID == QuoteID).Select(t => t.SupplierID).GroupBy(t => t).ToList();
```

I knew i had to only select the 1 field as LINQ would not know how to group if there were more fields with different values.

so im just trying to get some grouped IDs i can loop through, at the moment when i do a foreach on the below i get

```
strCurSupps = "System.Data.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata+Grouping`2[System.Int32,System.Int32],System.Data.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata+Grouping`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]"
```

Comment: Why do you want to group by that ID when your result has records only for that ID? What are you trying to do? Can you show some sample input and output?

Comment: your question is unclear! Please specify your input and desired output..Though you should be doing it like this: `db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Where(i => i.QuoteID == QuoteID).GroupBy(t => t.SupplierID)`

Comment: I need to get supplier IDs for a quote from my many to many joining table. but there are multiple copies for the supplier ID, at first i was getting ids of 1,4,1,4 i just need 1,4 so need to match the quote ID and show unqiue supplier IDs only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bah!

I was just missing item.Key i was using item and not item.key

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're getting a list of groups. When you iterate over that, each element of the iteration will be a group - which you can *also* iterate over. For example:

```
foreach (var group in currentSuppliers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group key: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var element in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Element: {0}", element);
    }
}
```

However, it's not clear what you're hoping to achieve to be honest - you're just going to get a sequence of groups, each of which will consist of a bunch of identical elements, because you're just getting the supplier ID. If you want the whole supplier, you need to get rid of the `Select(t => t.SupplierID)` and instead just use `GroupBy(t => t.SupplierID)`. Even *then*, you'll have a sequence of groups, each of which will contain several objects with the same `SupplierID` and the same `QuoteID`, presumably representing the same entity.